# 2 or 3 Checkboxes in MySQL query

Tags: mysql

I created the following SQL Query, which works fine. However, I want to add 2 other checkbox $Post's from another label. Now I'm a little bit without any idea how I can add it. Do I have to add an "AND" between the tbs queries?

Here is the code

```
include "db_connect.inc.php";

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM profiles";
    $sql .= " WHERE profilename = '". $_POST["profilename"] ."' ";
    $sql .= " AND ort = '". $_POST["ort"] ."' ";
    $sql .= "AND jahren = '" . $_POST["alter"] . "' ";

        $tbs = array();

foreach( array( 'tb1', 'tb2', 'tb3' ) as $tb_key )
{
    if ( empty( $_POST[$tb_key] ) ) continue;

    $tbs[] = "`grosse` LIKE '" . $_POST[$tb_key] . "'";
}
if ( !empty( $tbs ) )
{
    $sql .= ' AND ( ' . implode( ' OR ', $tbs ) . ' )';
}


        $tbs = array();

foreach( array( 'tb4', 'tb5', 'tb6', 'tb7' ) as $tb_key )
{
    if ( empty( $_POST[$tb_key] ) ) continue;

    $tbs[] = "`haare` LIKE '" . $_POST[$tb_key] . "'";
}
if ( !empty( $tbs ) )
{
    $sql .= ' AND ( ' . implode( ' OR ', $tbs ) . ' )';
}


$res = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

$num = mysqli_num_rows($res);
if ($num==0) echo "Kein Profil gefunden";
echo "<table border='1'>";

echo "<tr><td>Profile</td><td>Alter</td>";
echo "<td>Ort</td><td>Brustgrösse</td>";
echo "<td>Haarfarbe</td></tr>";
while ($dsatz = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res))
{
    echo "<tr>";    
    echo "<td>" .   $dsatz["profilename"] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>"     .$dsatz["jahren"] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>"     .$dsatz["ort"] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>"     .$dsatz["grosse"] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>"     .$dsatz["haare"] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}

        echo "</table>";
mysqli_close($con);
```

Answer (score 0):

i could it resolve it. I had a wrong entry in the DB. The query works fine!